# UICollectionview: didSelectItemAtIndexPath does not work with single tap. Works with two fingers and swipe only

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple UICollectionView with a single custom cell.  Everything is working as expected, but tapping any of the items in the collection does not seem to call the didSelectItemAtIndexPath event, except when:

A. Tapping with 2 fingers on the Cell
B. Swiping from either Left To Right or Right to Left

The cell contains 2 subviews, some objects on each.  All are marked with "Enable User Interaction".

BTW: I made sure I'm "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" and not "didDeselect..."

I don't want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to fix this as it seems "hacky".  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh.  I've just found the issue:

There was this gestureRecognizer attached to the view, which was trapping the single tap event.   I attached it to the required object and it all worked!

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: SearchBar, action: "resignFirstResponder"))
```